# Retrieve the list of tracking on a Data Extension via REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, rest, jobid

I'm trying to make an API call to, if possible, have the JobID of all sends done on this Data Extension. Is there a way to get the list of tracking on a data extension via REST API ? When you are on Marketing Cloud, you can see in "Tracking", all the sends linked to the data extension :
[image: tracking]

However on [the official doc on API calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm), I found nothing or not explicitly on tracking Data Extension. Do you have any ideas to get those without just copying from Marketing Cloud?

Comment: This would have to be done via SOAP API, not REST.

Comment: @Gortonington, I'm not convinced that you can actually achieve this using the SOAP API either. At least I can't find an object to return the JobID of sends based on a DE, but perhaps I am overlooking something? Which SOAP object are you referring to?

Comment: @Eliot Harper - I am on my phone, so resources limited, but likely using a retrieve on the Send SOAP object. I am shooting from hip though.